# WPF ListBox not effiecient when bind to observable collection that changes very often

Tags: c#, wpf

I need really efficient control in WPF that could depict up to tousands coloured Text.

Such control responsibility would be similar to Visual Studio Output.
Additionally it must be really efficient because I is supposed to to depict thousands of messages.

Any time new message appears then it should auto scroll to buttom

I used ListBox:

```
  <ListBox Name="ListBoxMessages" ItemsSource="{Binding ObservableMessages}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding  Info}" Foreground="{Binding Foreground}"  />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

ObservableMessages is of type: ObservableCollection of messages which contains info and colour.

It quite ok but when I tried to add autoscroll to button on each new item added to collection then it occurs to be really inefficient.

Thread.Sleep(5) helps a little bit but I am not sure if I want to use such workaround.

I investigated WPF RichTextBox so far but it seems really inefficient:
- I tried many solutions related to RichText box and it did not met my expectations.
- another solution would be to create my own control

Could you recommend any solution?

Observable collection is filled up very fast from different threads like this:

```
   public void ProcessNotificationMessage(Message message)
    {
      Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() => ObservableMessages.Add(message)));

        // Thread.Sleep(5);
    }
```

Comment: And your expectations that have not been met are?

Comment: it is not efficient enough, after long time it consumes too much memory

Comment: What is a "message"? Just a line of text? Does it include images? How long is each message, typically? What is the performance you need (operations/second)? What do you measure efficiency as? Memory, processor, space, etc?